# IE8 only using first session cookie

Tags: php, session

Some background information about the problem:

**My domain, is in this format:** http://example.com/
**Hosted On:** Shared Hosting Server.
**Protected Mode:** Off.
**Application suffers with:** IE8.
**Application doesn't suffer with:** Chrome, or FireFox.

I log in to the application with the following:

```
function login(){
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION['thumbprint']=nonce(session_id().'thumbprint',86400);
}


function nonce($str,$expires){
    global $config;
    return sha1(date('Y-m-d H:i',ceil(time()/$expires)*$expires).$salt.$str);
}
```

After logging in, I log out with:

```
function logout(){
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: http://example.com");
    die();
}
```

**The Problem:** If I log in, and log out, any other time I try to log in the session does not start. Why is this?

Comment: where's your `session_start();`?

Comment: you should be assuming something as elementary as that is included.

Comment: the most elementary things are the ones most commonly overlooked sometimes :)

Comment: well if you read the question you would have seen that ive already been able to log in which means session_start() is included...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I initially had:

```
session_regenerate_id();
```

But this will not work becuase according to PHP manual:

"session_regenerate_id() will replace the current session id with a new one, and keep the current session information."
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-regenerate-id.php

And becuase IE8:

"uses the first session cookie set and not the last as in Firefox."
http://anvilstudios.co.za/blog/php/session-cookies-faulty-in-ie8/

To fix this problem all you need to do is set:

```
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

Which deletes old session id and forces IE8 to use the new one.